# What are some of your favorite examples of websites presenting long form text (essays, long articles, etc.) in an interesting and/or unique manner?

Tags: website-design, text

I am going to put together a simple Webflow website which will feature a ~2,000 word essay on the homepage. I am looking for creative ways to present the essay in a way that is interesting/unique, but also readable. Any examples you all can provide would be extremely appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Hi Mark, welcome to UX Stack Exchange. Questions that ask for general examples are considered off-topic here. Can you edit your question to describe the problem that you're working on, what you've tried so far, and why you are asking for help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Pitchfork used to do these gorgeous long-form editorials, and [the one they did on Bat for Lashes](https://pitchfork.com/features/cover-story/reader/bat-for-lashes/) is a great example that feels highly interactive and experimental but still has incredibly readable text.

Comment: Pitchfork was my first thought as well! They were amazing... haven't looked lately to see if they've kept it up.